# How to replace all string except specific part in string

Tags: java, regex, string, java-8

I have a string `abc____2019____5_10_40_56_20190319213500.pdf` and I want to replace string which is before `date stamp`.

Can any one give a suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: share your code. what you've done so far

Comment: check my answer it might help u bro !!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are three simple ways of doing it.

Non-regex way. Just split using `_` and get the last item from array using this code,

```
String s = "abc____2019____5_10_40_56_20190319213500.pdf";
String[] data = s.split("_");
System.out.println(data[data.length-1]);
```

Prints,

```
20190319213500.pdf
```

Regex way is even cooler, with one liner code. Replace everything from start till last occurrence of underscore,

```
String s = "abc____2019____5_10_40_56_20190319213500.pdf";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("^.*_", ""));
```

Prints,

```
20190319213500.pdf
```

Still another way using `find` method in `Matcher` would be to find the last digit pattern followed by any non-digit pattern till end of line using this code,

```
String s = "abc____2019____5_10_40_56_20190319213500.pdf";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\D*$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
} else {
    System.out.println("Didn't find");
}
```

Prints,

```
20190319213500.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hey use the length of the timestamp and length of the string to handle
>   this.please my code below it will help you

```
 String sample = "abc____2019____5_10_40_56_20190319213500";
 int lengthOfTimestamp = 25;
 String value = sample.substring(sample.length() -lengthOfTimestamp ,sample.length());
 System.out.println("value :"+value);
```

output:

```
value : 5_10_40_56_20190319213500
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for regex :) Just split the whole string by last occurence of underscore:

```
String s = "abc____2019____5_10_40_56_20190319213500.pdf";
s = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("_"));
```

Or if you want to replace that part before, you might use:

```
String s = "abc____2019____5_10_40_56_20190319213500.pdf";
s = "replacment" + s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("_") + 1);
```